# Discord Api Valid intents must be provided for the Client but the code dosent work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, ws

I set up the

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```

for my discord.js bot.

But now I just get the error message:

> Uncaught c:\Users\niko\Documents\bot\receptionist\index.js:8

The line 8 in my index.js is this:

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```

Comment: try replacing the parameter of `new Client` with  `{ intents : Object.keys(Discord.Intents.FLAGS) }`

Comment: i replace it with const client = { intents : Object.keys(Discord.Intents.FLAGS) }
and i still have the same problem

Comment: You shouldn't enable all intents. This will slowdown your client and is unnecessary. Enable the intents you need as you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the first line of the code which states:

```js
  
 const Discord = require('discord.js')
```

and also delete the third line of the code which follows :

```js
const client= new Discord.Client()
```

because you're declaring the client with the intents below after declaring the
**prefix**.
And also delete

```js
const bot = client
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed, Presence, Collection, Interaction } = require ('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]
});
```

Comment: same thing it still dosent worck
same problem
Uncaught c:\Users\nemson\Documents\bot\bot\index.js:8

Comment: can you show us the full code? It might be possible, we can find the solution after that..

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You're right. My mistake.

Comment: @Shadow_storme  Hi I'm a total beginner to node.js. Why did this work?